# How do I get only specific level of message in my log file?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am trying to write logs in two files, in one file I am ok to get the logs of any level, and in other file I am looking for only INFO level. Is this possible?

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>c:/log/myLogFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EVENTS_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>c:/log/myLogFile-event.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>../logs/cweo-app-event-%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- <logger name="event" level="DEBUG"> <appender-ref ref="EVENTS_FILE" 
        /> </logger> -->
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="EVENTS_FILE" />
    </root>
```

This is my `logback.xml` where in `EVENTS_FILE` I want to print only `INFO` messages nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't use `ThresholdFilter`, use [`LevelFilter`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/filter/LevelFilter.html).

`LevelFilter` provides equality testing, unlike `ThresholdFilter`. See [Filters.](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html)

In this case:

```
<appender name="EVENTS_FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>c:/log/myLogFile-event.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
      <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
```